# Number of ways the letters in "anagram" can be arranged?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In class we are beginning discrete probability and we are being introduced to counting. He said in an example today that the word "anagram" (which has $7$ letters) can be rearranged to have $7!/3!$ possible words when we don't count the order of the a's. To me this seemed like a combination but this result reduces to $7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4$ which means we are choosing $7$ letters on $4$ spots. So a bit confused if anyone could help?

Comment: Your title is misleading.  We do care about the order of the letters.  However, we are only interested in distinguishable arrangements of the letters of the word *anagram*, so we do not care about permutations of the three *a*s among themselves.

Comment: What does “without order” mean?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, I have suggested an edit to the title that previously (incorrectly, as you pointed out) stated "the order does not matter". More than one year on, having a more accurate title seems more useful. Commenting here so your comment can be understood.

Comment: @user35395 That is not a correct duplicate. I saw one other post you flagged as a duplicate which was also inappropriate. Please read more carefully.

Answer (score 4):

This can be explained as the following using multiplication principle:

- Pick which of the seven available spaces is occupied by the `n`
- Pick which of the six remaining available spaces is occupied by the `g`
- $\vdots$
- Pick which of the four remaining spaces is occupied by the `m`
- All remaining three spaces will be occupied by the `a`'s.

Applying multiplication principle, there are $7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4$ ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Your instructor is counting distinguishable arrangements of the word *anagram*.

The word *anagram* has seven letters, so we have seven positions to fill with $3$ *a*s, $1$ *g*, $1$ *m*, and $1$ *r*.  We can fill three of these seven positions with *a*s in $\binom{7}{3}$ ways.  The remaining four letters are distinct, so they can be arranged in the remaining four positions in $4!$ ways.  Hence, the number of distinguishable arrangements of the word *anagram* is 
$$\binom{7}{3}4! = \frac{7!}{3!4!} \cdot 4! = \frac{7!}{3!}$$ 
The factor of $3!$ in the denominator represents the number of ways the three *a*s can be permuted among themselves within a given arrangement of the letters of the word *anagram* without producing an arrangement distinguishable from the given arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you notice is that the process reminds you of the number of permutations (not selections, as you wrote) of $4$ out of $7$ objects. This is indeed the case.

Now, first note that to count the number of arrangements of $n$ *distinct* objects, you may proceed as follows:

Partition the set in two, one containing $r$ of these $n$ objects. Then the number of arrangements is (by the multiplication principle) $$nPr\times (n-r)P(n-r)=nPr\times (n-r)!=n!.$$ This means that for each arrangement of the $r$ objects in the first part, we have $(n-r)!$ arrangements of the $n$ objects. *Now, if these $n-r$ objects are indistinguishable, then the number of permutations of the $n$ (previously distinct) objects should be divided by $(n-r)!.$* This is what you noticed; and, as I have explained, hopefully you can see why it is true that **the number of arrangements of $n$ objects, $n-r$ of which are indistinguishable, is the same as the number of arrangements of $r$ out of $n$ *distinct* objects.**